# Bash Alias to perform Alt+1?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal, bash-alias

Using Ubuntu I can create a terminal with two tabs:
`gnome-terminal --tab --tab`

However, by default it goes to the last created tab.  Using `Alt + 1` I can make it go to the first, but I want to avoid key presses.

I'd like to either create an alias to execute `Alt + 1` in bash, or directly insert similar code: `gnome-terminal --tab --tab -e "alt1"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This works but it's a bit kludgey and requires [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/):

```
gnome-terminal --tab --tab --tab -e 'xdotool key alt+1'
```